# How to serialize an XmlDocument to a well-formatted human-readable XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I use an `XmlDocument.WriteTo(XmlWriter)` method to serialize an `XmlDocument` to a text file. I have also tried `XmlDocument.OuterXml`. Both output a single-line XML text which is very hard (up to impossible in case of a reasonably big XML document) to read for a human.

Is there a way to output a well-formatted human-readable XML text instead? I mean with every element starting at a new line and indentation used to visualize hierarchy levels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree to BoltClock. 
Here is the sample code-

```
//Create a writer to write XML to the console.
XmlTextWriter writer = null;
writer = new XmlTextWriter (Console.Out);
//Use indentation for readability.
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
writer.Indentation = 4;
```

Comment: It seems quite unnecessary to add a totally separate answer just to say you agree and provide sample code in which only one line matters.

Comment: An answer with a good code sample always wins, @BoltClock, even when it is not really necessary. But I recognize the fact you were the first to answer and value your participation, that's why I have also upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `XmlTextWriter` to write to the file, you can set its [`Formatting` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.formatting.aspx) to `Formatting.Indented` before you write.